# Import data to Hdfs from AWS S3 using Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, sqoop

I am using `distcp`(For Batch data) to get data from S3.

But according to sqoop website we can import from s3 to hdfs. I tried but I get error every time for `connection build error` :

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.7/user/examples/S3Import.html

So, is there anyone who can tell me how I can do this perfectly ?

Also, What I can do to get auto syncing of incremental data.

Comment: Have you actually built and are running that version of Sqoop? Or is it from EMR? What is wrong with running distcp from an Oozie or Cron schedule?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at `s3distcp` instead. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/seven-tips-for-using-s3distcp-on-amazon-emr-to-move-data-efficiently-between-hdfs-and-amazon-s3/